# Error Xaml namespace

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am following a tutorial to implement a value converter. I receive an error for this code:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    //
}

<Application
x:Class="TestApp10.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestApp10"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TrueToVisibleConverter" />
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="FalseToVisibleConverter" IsReversed="True" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I get an error

> The name "BooleanToVisibilityConverter" does not exist in the namespace "using:TestApp10"

The function is defined in the App.xaml.cs file.

Thank you.

Comment: It resolved the error,Thx. but the code is still not working (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333533/trouble-binding-xaml-uwp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an intellisense error in XAML Designer. Please make sure you have implemented your `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` correctly. Then you can try with following steps to fix this error.

1. Open your project in File Explorer, delete ***bin*** and ***obj*** folder
2. In Visual Studio, right-click your Solution, and select **Clean**.
3. Right-click your Solution, and select **Rebuild**.

After this, your error should be gone. If you still get this error, you can try to reopen your project in Visual Studio.